# Stop some content scrolling in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I am using different templates in Ionic for each View.  I want the search bar to remain in the same place and allow the results to scroll but currently the whole view is scrolling.  Thoughts?

Record album

```
    <span class="item-note">
      Grammy
    </span>
  </button>
  <div class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchTerm">
  </div>
</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="psalm in psalms | filter: {psalm: searchTerm}" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/psalm/{{psalm.id}}">
    <h2>Psalm {{psalm.psalm}} {{psalm.version}}</h2>
    <p>{{psalm.metre}}</p>
    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable scrolling for your parent `<ion-content>` via `scroll="false"` and add `<ion-scroll>`.

Your `<ion-list>` would be wrapped like this:

```
<ion-scroll direction="y">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-icon-right" ng-repeat="psalm in psalms | filter: {psalm: searchTerm}" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/psalm/{{psalm.id}}">
            <h2>Psalm {{psalm.psalm}} {{psalm.version}}</h2>
            <p>{{psalm.metre}}</p>
            <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-scroll>
```

See [***ion-scroll***](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/) and [***ion-content***](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionContent)

Answer (score 1):

iWörk's answer is correct. If you not able to get scrolling give height to the ion-scroll.

Do following steps.

- Disable the scroll of ion-content `<ion-content scroll="false">`
- Add `<ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 500px">` to the content that you need to have scroll

```html
<ion-content scroll="false">
  <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height: 500px">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="item in data.items">
        <!-- Content goes here-->
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```